# Starting the broadcast receiver when ever new sms arrives

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have created a remote service which , is calling a broadcast receiver which in turn call the alarm manager for triggering the alarm , but i want to trigger the receiver through the rempte service when ever a new message arrives

The piece of code is as follows:

```
     @Override
                public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onBind()");

                    return myRemoteServiceStub;
                }           

                    private IMyRemoteService.Stub myRemoteServiceStub = new IMyRemoteService.Stub() {
                        public int getCounter() throws RemoteException {
                //          startAlarmNotification();

                            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                            filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                            filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
                            filter.addAction("your_action_strings"); //further more
                            filter.addAction("your_action_strings"); //further more

                            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                            return counter;
                        }
                    };

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate() {
                        super.onCreate();
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"onCreate()");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroy() {
                        super.onDestroy();
                        serviceHandler.removeCallbacks(myTask);
                        serviceHandler = null;
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"onDestroy()");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                        super.onStart(intent, startId);
                        serviceHandler = new Handler();
                        serviceHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 1000L);
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStart()");
                    }

                    class Task implements Runnable {
                        public void run() {
                            ++counter;
                            serviceHandler.postDelayed(this,1000L);
                            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Incrementing counter in the run method");
                        }
                    }
                    public void  startAlarmNotification(){
                      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                      calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                      Intent alarmintent = new Intent(RemoteService.this, AlarmReciver.class);
                      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationId, alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                //        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  60 * 1000, sender);
                          am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                    }


                    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                           @Override
                           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                              String action = intent.getAction();
                              if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                                //action for sms received
                                        startAlarmNotification();
                                        unregisterReceiver(receiver);


                              }
                              else if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
                                   //action for phone state changed
                              }     
                           }
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working if your service is running... so below code is run whenever you get SMS. you can modify this like after get SMS you can start service and put your code in to servies.

SmsReceiver JAVA Class

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           if (extras == null)
           return;

          // To display a Toast whenever there is an SMS.
           Toast.makeText(context,"Recieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
           for (int i = 0; i &lt; pdus.length; i++) {
              SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
              String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
              String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
              Toast.makeText(context, ""+sender+":"+body , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
           startAlarmNotification();
         }

        public void  startAlarmNotification(){
                      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                      calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                      Intent alarmintent = new Intent(RemoteService.this, AlarmReciver.class);
                      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationId, alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                //        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  60 * 1000, sender);
                          am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                    }
     }
```

in your manifest do below code :

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

also add below permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```